# JSON.parse unexpected character localStorage

Tags: reactjs, json, local-storage

I am trying to save data to localStorage but I am getting error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Blogs.css";

//getting values from localstorage
const getDataFromLS = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("blogs");
  data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
};

export const Blogs = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(getDataFromLS());

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  const handleAddBlogSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let blog = {
      title: title,
      author: author,
    };
    setBlogs([...blogs, blog]);
    setTitle("");
    setAuthor("");
  };

  useEffect(
    (blogs) => {
      localStorage.setItem("blogs", JSON.stringify(blogs));
    },
    [blogs]
  );

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div>
        <form className="form-control" onSubmit={handleAddBlogSubmit}>
          <label>Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
            value={title}
          />
          <label>Author</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => setAuthor(event.target.value)}
            value={author}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="blogs-list">Blog List Here</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I checked JSON.parse documentation. I am passing string "blogs" in JSON.parse. But I may have done something wrong elsewhere as I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with your `getDataFromLS` function. It is not returning the parsed data from localStorage.

```
const getDataFromLS = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("blogs");
  return data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
};
```

Also why are you passing `blogs` to a callback function inside `useEffect`? Make it like this

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      localStorage.setItem("blogs", JSON.stringify(blogs || []));
    },
    [blogs]
  );
```

Lastly, clear your local storage, you probably have undefined assigned to `blogs`

Comment: Saying unexpected character at this line:  "return JSON.parse(data);"

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

//getting values from localstorage
const getDataFromLS = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("blogs");
  console.log("data==========", data);
  const a = data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
  console.log("a=========", a);
};

export const Blogs = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  const handleAddBlogSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("e.target");
    e.preventDefault();
    let blog = {
      title: title,
      author: author,
    };

    console.log("blog", blog);
    setBlogs((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, blog];
    });

    console.log("blogss", blogs);
    setTitle("");
    setAuthor("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("blog");
    localStorage.setItem("blogs", JSON.stringify(blogs));
    getDataFromLS();
  }, [blogs]);

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div>
        <form className="form-control" onSubmit={handleAddBlogSubmit}>
          <label>Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
            value={title}
          />
          <label>Author</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => setAuthor(event.target.value)}
            value={author}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="blogs-list">Blog List Here</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("blog");
    localStorage.setItem("blogs", JSON.stringify(blogs));
    getDataFromLS();
  }, [blogs]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what u doing is calling the getDataFromLS()  directly to the useState react hook. 
So, when u call the setBlogs() method inside the handlefunction , the method calls the getDataFromLS()  function instead of setting the value to the blogs variable.

so in useEffect() hook there are no changes in blogs so it will not run and u will get undefined while setting the value to the local storage. Thats why u are not getting value from local storage .

or, urs blogs value is not changing that's why useEffect() hook will not be called and u  will get undefined